# ffmpeg complex filters results in lower video quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am having issues with a complex filter, I scaled it to 720p but it still outputs a low quality image. I can confirm that the input source is in 720p but what comes out seems more like 240p.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8" -i ./public/images/ACE.png -i ./public/images/logo2.jpg -i ./public/images/crunchy.png -i ./public/images/red.jpg -filter_complex \
    "[0]scale=1290:720,setsar=1[ovrl0]; \
     [1]scale=40:40[ovrl1]; \
     [2]scale=40:40[ovrl2]; \
     [3]scale=40:40[ovrl3]; \
     [4]scale=40:40[ovrl4]; \
     [ovrl0][ovrl1] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='lt(mod(t,40),10)'[v1]; \
     [v1][ovrl2] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='between(mod(t,40),10,20)'[v2]; \
     [v2][ovrl3] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='gt(mod(t,40),20)'[v3]; \
     [v3][ovrl4] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='gt(mod(t,40),30)'" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/2222-2222-2222-2222"
```

console output

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear2/prog_index.m3u8' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear3/prog_index.m3u8' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence0.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear2/fileSequence0.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear3/fileSequence0.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/fileSequence0.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:30:01.00, start: 10.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 200000
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 200000
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 192x144, 14.99 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 200000
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 311111
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x240, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 311111
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 311111
  Program 2 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 484444
    Stream #0:4: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x360, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 484444
    Stream #0:5: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 484444
  Program 3 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 737777
    Stream #0:6: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x360, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 737777
    Stream #0:7: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 737777
Input #1, png_pipe, from './public/images/ACE.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 200x200 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from './public/images/logo2.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49832 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2371x1967 [SAR 300:300 DAR 2371:1967], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, png_pipe, from './public/images/crunchy.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 225x225, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #4, image2, from './public/images/red.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4862 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 482x372 [SAR 300:300 DAR 241:186], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #3:0 (png) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #4:0 (mjpeg) -> scale (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7f9fdf071c00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f9fde9bc400] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7f9fe0034800] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f9fe0034800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7f9fe0034800] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x7f9fe0034800] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=14 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/2222-2222-2222-2222':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1290x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:24], q=-1--1, 14.99 fps, 1k tbn, 14.99 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 200000
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence1.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] No longer receiving playlist 1
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] No longer receiving playlist 2
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] No longer receiving playlist 3
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence2.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence3.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence4.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence5.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9fdf002200] Opening 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1
```

Comment: Not possible to provide any suggestions without seeing the complete log/console output from this command.

Comment: Ah right so sorry, always forget that is the important part, I've just updated the question with the console output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your m3u8 input contains four video streams: the smallest size being 192x144 and the largest size is only 480x360. The console output shows that the 192x144 stream is selected. You are upscaling to 1290x720. Upscaling from 192x144 (or 480x360) to 1290x720 will look crappy no matter what.

Recommended solution is to find an input with a higher resolution and avoid upscaling.

Comment: So if I had a higher input (like 1080p) it should work fine? How would I choose the 480x360 stream?

Comment: @Ricky 1) Yes 2) It will automatically select the stream with the highest resolution if you use scale with no preceding stream name, but by using `[0]` it chose the first video stream it encountered which was 192x144. Alternatively, for this exact stream scheme you could use `[0:4]` or `[0:6]` as they are both 480x360.

Comment: Your suggestions worked! Thank you lordNeckbeard you rock.